# Way to find out which button was clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

I want to find out what button was clicked during post back.

So if the user clicks a button.. It goes to postback, then to the controls Click event.

What I want to do is to find out what button was clicked during the first stage. During the PostBack stage.

Is there a way to achieve that?

ps. c# code only. It is an asp.net question

Comment: Matrix001, just to clarify your terminology, the postback is when the user does an action on their web browser (or an automated client side action occurs) which causes a HTTP post request to be sent back to the server.  What you refer to as the "PostBack stage" is actually the first few stages of the page lifecycle which occur before postback event handling (such as button click events).  I assume what you are interested in is getting information on upcoming postback events while handling an earlier event such as `Page.Load`.

Comment: Yes, What i want is to get the type of event of the fired control (or alternatively simply the controls identity) as soon as the user requests information i.e. clicks on the button. I want to know which button was clicked..if it was button A or B, ..but i want to know it on the Page.Load event

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check `__EVENTTARGET` and the `Form` collection with code similar to this (shamelessly stolen from [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/749077.aspx/1)).

```
public static System.Web.UI.Control GetPostBackControl(System.Web.UI.Page page)
{
    Control control = null;
    string ctrlname = page.Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"];
    if (ctrlname != null && ctrlname != String.Empty)
    {
        control = page.FindControl(ctrlname);
    }
    // if __EVENTTARGET is null, the control is a button type and we need to 
    // iterate over the form collection to find it
    else
    {
        string ctrlStr = String.Empty;
        Control c = null;
        foreach (string ctl in page.Request.Form)
        {
            // handle ImageButton controls ...
            if (ctl.EndsWith(".x") || ctl.EndsWith(".y"))
            {
                ctrlStr = ctl.Substring(0, ctl.Length - 2);
                c = page.FindControl(ctrlStr);
            }
            else
            {
                c = page.FindControl(ctl);
            }
            if (c is System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button ||
                        c is System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton)
            {
                control = c;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return control;
}
```

Call it in `Page_Load` like this:

```
Control controlThatCausedPostBack = GetPostBackControl(this);
```

Comment: It tells me that the method doesnt exist in the current context. I did this: System.Web.UI.Control cont = new Control();
            cont = ControlGetPostBackControl(this);

Comment: How do you put it in my code...why does it say it doesnt exist in the current context

Comment: Sorry, I got it to work..Awesome code..Thanks..for the answer!! I am glad i asked someone!!!

Answer (score 0):

Just use a private variable on your web page. In the `OnClick` handler, set the value of that variable to the `sender` argument (you'll need to typecast it to a Button or Control).

Comment: I think it isn't an answer for @Matrix001 question. He asks about something else. IMHO he asks - how to get button's name in `Page_Load` after postback.

Comment: Not exactly a name..But identity that it is a button A that was pressed and not Button B

Comment: wsanville. i need to get the values of the button in the postback stage, and not when the button fires the event which occurs later. As soon as there is a postback and the pageLoad event is fired. I want to know in that event ..that button A was pressed